# Submenues wont show up in my mobile dropdown

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

On small screens I have a hamburger menu that drops down to show a some list items. I am trying to add sub-menus onto some of these items.

I have tried multiple variations of inserting submenus but none appear. The regular hamburger dropdown functions fine but doesn't change at all when I add the submenus.

Here is the html **without** adding submenus.

```
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span>    </label>
  <ul class="menu">
       <li><a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Property Information</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Home Financing</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Loan Approval</a></li>    
       <li><a href="#">Loan Closing</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Home Ownership</a></li>
  </ul>
```

How would I add a submenu to this within one of those items?

Comment: This looks like it might be bootstrap related. Perhaps adding something like this would help: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3 - It uses the "dropdown" facility, but you could probably integrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `ul` inside the appropriate `li` block as below.  You will need to play with the css to make it display appropriately.

**HTML**

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Property Information</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Property Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Property Information 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home Financing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Loan Approval</a></li>    
            <li><a href="#">Loan Closing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home Ownership</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
    <style>
        nav ul ul {
            display: none;
        }
        nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
```